# @permission-required argument in django

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-permissions

In a Django project I want to limit viewing of some `views` to admin (the user for which `request.user.is_superuser` is `True`)
I know that I must use `@permission_required(...)` before that view, but what is the argument for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superusers are not handled by permission, they're handled solely by the `is_superuser` field. You can use the `@user_passes_test` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_superuser)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```